# how to avoid a tkinter entry widget to lose focus when a notebook tab is selected from a callback

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have an entry widget that has a callback binded to `<Key>`
whenever the user types something in the entry widget then the callback
mapped to `<Key>` is called. the callback gets the text that was inserted in the entry widget then attempts to find a Notebook tab whose title matches the text. if it matches then it calls the `Notebook.select` method. when the `Notebook.select` method is called the tab is selected and one of its child widget gets focused. this behavior isnt desired i need the entry widget to hold the focus. it basically is losing the focus when the callback calls `Notebook.select`. i have used `grab_set()` in the entry widget but it doesnt avoid it losing focus when the method notebook select is called.

Comment: Have you tried `.focus_set()` method of entry widget at the end of your callback?

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This behavior may be platform dependent. When I select a tab on my machine the focus stays with the entry widget. However, if your platform changes the focus you can easily set the focus back from within your callback.

Here's a working example. Run the code, and when you type in the name of a tab (eg: "two"), the tab will be selected but the focus should remain in the entry widget:

```
entry .e
ttk::notebook .nb

pack .e -side top -fill x
pack .nb -side top -fill both -expand 1

foreach text {"One" "Two" "Three" "Four"} {
    set frame_name ".nb.page_$text"
    frame $frame_name
    .nb add $frame_name -text $text
    label $frame_name.label -text "This is page $text"
    pack $frame_name.label -padx 20 -pady 20
}

bind .e <KeyRelease> callback

proc callback {} {
    set input [string tolower [.e get]]
    foreach child [winfo children .nb] {
        set text [string tolower [.nb tab $child -text]]
        if {$text eq $input} {
            .nb select $child
            focus .e
        }
    }
}
```